# Were Vasquez and Drake lovers?

Tags: alien-franchise, aliens-1986

On my numerous watches of James Cameron's *Aliens* I had always had the strong impression that Vasquez and Drake were lovers.

However comments in another question made me question if this was actually the case or not.

**Is there anything within scripts, or the expanded universe that confirms if Drake or Vasquez were lovers or just close friends?**

Comment: I've listens to the audio book of the novel. And I don't recall them being mentioned as lovers

Comment: *"However comments in another question.."* What question? Link to it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I cannot find the question anymore, it was asking  if Hudson had any friends.

Comment: There is an answer to this question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/alt.cult-movies.alien/kmIP7uO4MCU/Xldwv05_URIJ).

Comment: It might help to post snippets from the script or video clips supporting your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, there's nothing canon that confirms they're lovers, but it seems some people suspected it in-universe as well.

Vasquez and Drake met each other in juvenile prison after they had both committed murders at a young age (*Alien: The Archive*, page 121). They became close friends, and enlisted in the USCM together to get out of prison. They went to boot camp together, were assigned to the same unit, and enlisted in advanced weapons training.

Their smartgun instructor called them "the sweethearts" because they were so close, but they both denied being in a romantic relationship (*Alien: The Weyland-Yutani Report*, page 96).